# "mui-one-time-password-input" is not working with "formik"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I am working on a Next.js Project, and I have to use `mui-one-time-password-input` library for OTP input. and for form validation I am using `formik`.

Now, when I try to apply `value` and `onChange` properties to `MuiOtpInput` component; Somehow, it is not accepting any input I provide in that MuiOtpInput field.

```js
const OtpForm = () => {
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            otp: null,
            submit: null
        },
        validationSchema: Yup.object({
            otp: Yup
                .string()
                .length(6, 'Must be a valid OTP')
                .required('OTP is required')
        })
    });

    return (
        <form>
            <MuiOtpInput
                TextFieldsProps={{
                    placeholder: '-'
                }}
                onComplete={formik.handleSubmit}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                value={formik.values.otp}
                length={OTP_LENGTH}
            />
        </form>
    );
};
```

This works though...

```js
const OtpForm = () => {
    const [otp,setOtp] = useState('')

    return (
        <form>
            <MuiOtpInput
                TextFieldsProps={{
                    placeholder: '-'
                }}                
                onChange={(val) => setOtp(val)}
                value={otp}
                length={OTP_LENGTH}
            />
        </form>
    );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that MuiOtpInput lacks support for the 'name' property, which might be causing the issue. To fix this issue you can use formik.setFieldValue(fieldName, value), Here's an example code snippet:

```
const OtpForm = () => {
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            otp: null,
            submit: null
        },
        validationSchema: Yup.object({
            otp: Yup
                .string()
                .length(6, 'Must be a valid OTP')
                .required('OTP is required')
        })
    });

    return (
        <form>
            <MuiOtpInput
                TextFieldsProps={{
                    placeholder: '-'
                }}
                onComplete={formik.handleSubmit}
                onChange={(value) => formik.setFieldValue("otp", value)}
                value={formik.values.otp}
                length={OTP_LENGTH}
            />
        </form>
    );
};
```